# Getting map data using React from firestore

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to get map data from Firestore in reactjs. My code keeps erroring saying "Objects are not valid as a React". Can someone point me to an example or show me one with my database below?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { firestore } from "../../../FireBase/FireBase";
import CartItem from "./CartItem";
const CartPage = (props) => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCart = async () => {
      const doc = await firestore
        .collection("Users")
        .doc("CfL5uszL3CTE1nIQTgDrKK5q4OV2")
        .get();

      const data = doc.data();
      console.log("data " + data);
      if (!data) {
        // document didn't exist
        console.log("hit null");
        setCart(null)
      } else {
        console.log("hit");
        setCart(data.cart);
      }
      console.log("cart " + cart);
    }

    fetchCart();
  }, []);

  if (!cart) {
    // You can render a placeholder if you like during the load, or just return null to render nothing.
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="cartpage">
      <h1>cart</h1>
      <div className="cart">
        {cart.map(cartItem => (
          <div key={cartItem.id}>{cartItem.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartPage;
```

[image: Firestore database]

Comment: Can you share your code on codesandbox or similar platform ? It is hard to debug it from image.

Comment: @TomaszKisiel  I have added my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your getting is because you're returning a promise from your component (You've made it an async function, and async functions return promises). Promises and other arbitrary objects cannot be returned from rendering in react. You need to have a state variable for holding your data. On the first render, you'll have no data, and then you'll use a useEffect to fetch the data and update the state

Additionally, you have some mistakes with how you're trying to get the data and access it. You're calling `.get("Cf...V2")`, but .get doesn't take a parameter. If you want to specify which document to get, you use the `.doc()` function for that. .get() will then return a promise, so you need to await that before trying to access any properties on it. The data you get will be an object with all the properties on the right hand side of your screenshot, and you will need to pluck the cart property out of that.

In short, i recommend something like the following:

```
const CartPage = (props) => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCart = async () => {
      const doc = await firestore
        .collection("Users")
        .doc("CfL5uszL3CTE1nIQTgDrKK5q4OV2")
        .get();

      const data = doc.data();
      if (!data) {
        // document didn't exist
        setCart(null)
      } else {
        setCart(data.cart);
      }
    }

    fetchCart();
  }, []);

  if (!cart) {
    // You can render a placeholder if you like during the load, or just return null to render nothing.
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="cartpage">
      <h1>cart</h1>
      <div className="cart">
        {cart.map(cartItem => (
          <div key={cartItem.id}>{cartItem.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have implemented your code add I'm getting some errors. Here are the console logs data [object Object] 
 hit 
 cart null

Comment: Without knowing what code you added, i don't know the significance of those log statements.

Comment: So I think it has to do with how you called cart from the user. Do you know why cart is null?

Comment: I copied your code to try and play with it to make sure it worked. So the code I ran is the updated code above for the question. I just added logs to see how yours was working

Comment: `data [object Object]` This means it got the data back. You can view it better if you change the log statement to `console.log('data', data)`. `hit` This is confirming that it went into the `else`. `cart null` This is telling you that the value of `cart` was null **when the effect started**. This is completely expected. Calling setCart is not going to change the value of a local const, so this log statement isn't useful. If you want to verify that the component rerendered, then put a log statement in the body of your component, not in the effect.

Comment: my apologizes your code is right i just made stupid mistakes when changing things and looking at logs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that you can create async component in this way. What you return in your component should be simple JSX code. If you want to do something asynchronously inside component you should wrap this inside useEffect hook.

```
const CartPage = (props) => {
  const [ cart, setCart ] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const inner = async () => {
      const ref = await firestore
        .collection("Users")
        .get("CfL5uszL3CTE1nIQTgDrKK5q4OV2").cart;

      setCart(
        ref.map((item) => ({
          id: item.id,
          name: item.name
        }))
      );
    };

    inner();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="cartpage">
      <h1>cart</h1>
      <div className="cart"></div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Now i am getting an error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Comment: It's mean that ref is not an array. Probably there is some problem with this command ```firestore.collection("Users").get("CfL5uszL3CTE1nIQTgDrKK5q4OV2").cart;``` It is correct collection name and correct id ?